# performance testing with jmeter using auth which has a token

Tags: api, oauth, jmeter

I have rest api which has token in header, but i'm having trouble performing with response data because api have to request token, where should i store my token in jmeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you just have the token and looking for a way to add it to the request(s) - it can be done via [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), you can configure it to send [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header as:

   [image]
2. If you need to authenticate/authorize first than you can implement the authorization logic using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers first and once you get the token in the response you can extract it from there using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

   Then in the HTTP Header Manager you will be able to use the JMeter Variable extracted by the Post-Processor. See [Using Regular Expressions to Extract Tokens and Session IDs to Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-tokens-and-session-ids-to-variables) article for example implementation